# How to wait for user input in a dialog?

Tags: java, android

I have a program that was written in vb.net that is now to be written in java using android studio. Trying to mimic same flow as original program.

I am at a section where after something is enter I go into database and retrieve records. In my example it has 2 records. I am trying to step through each record and ask user for input. total of up to 4 inputs per record.

I have been trying to accomplish this during a for loop. (I am more a windows programmer .net so I am not familiar with Java) In windows you just pop a messagebox (they are in modal mode so program stops and waits for the input before proceeding.)

Here is where I am.

For each iteration I need to ask questions. I have tried dialogs and dialogFragment.

```
                       if (addNew.equals("Y")) {

                           final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ReturnAreaActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_location);
                            dialog.setTitle("New Location Setup");
                            TextView message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.theText);
                            message.setText("Is this location a Pick Bin");
                            Button buttonYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
                            Button buttonNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
                            dialog.show();
                            dialog.setCancelable(false);
                            buttonYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    PickBinFlag="Y" ;
                                    myField = "QTY";
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    location_Type = "P";
                                    mILM=ItemLevelsModel.getInstance();
                                    mylevels = DatabaseMgr.GetItemLevels(IsItem);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < mylevels.size(); i++) {
                                        String lLvl = mylevels.get(i).getitemLevel().toString();
                                        String lLvlD = mylevels.get(i).getItemLvlDesc().toString();
                                        CheckPicking(IsItem, lLvl, lLvlD);
                                        if (PickBinFlag.equals("Y")){
                                            final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(ReturnAreaActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                                            dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_minmax);
                                            TextView message = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.minMax);
                                            TextView theText = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.theText);
                                            if (whichQTY.equals("MAX")){
                                                dialog1.setTitle("Enter Max QTY");
                                                message.setText("MAX");
                                                theText.setText("Enter Max QTY for this location");
                                            }else{
                                                dialog1.setTitle("Enter Min QTY");
                                                message.setText("MAX");
                                                theText.setText("Enter Min QTY for this location");
                                            }
                                            final TextView maxQTY = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.editAmt);
                                            Button button1 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                                            Button button2 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
                                            Button button3 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
                                            Button button4 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
                                            Button button5 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
                                            Button button6 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
                                            Button button7 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn7);
                                            Button button8 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn8);
                                            Button button9 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn9);
                                            Button button0 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn0);
                                            Button buttonEnter = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
                                            Button buttonClear = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
                                            dialog1.show();
                                            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "1";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "2";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "3";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "4";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "5";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "6";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "7";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "8";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "9";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });

                                            button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = mPin + "0";
                                                    maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                                                }
                                            });


                                            buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mMax = Integer.parseInt(mPin);
                                                    if (whichQTY.equals("Max")) {
                                                        mMax = Integer.parseInt(mPin);
                                                        whichQTY = "Min";
                                                    } else {
                                                        mMin = Integer.parseInt(mPin);
                                                        whichQTY = "Max";
                                                    }
                                                    mPin = "";

                                                    dialog1.dismiss();
                                                    return;
                                                }

                                            });

                                            buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    mPin = "";
                                                    maxQTY.setText("");
                                                }
                                            });

                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            });

                            buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    PickBinFlag="N";
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    myField = "QTY";

                                    return;
                                }
                            });
/*                                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                            dialog.show();*/
                        }else{
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {

                    }

                }
            }else{
                // we are in QTY field.

                mQTY.setText(scanner.getScanResult());
            }

        }
    };
}

public void CheckPicking(String myItem,String myLevel,String myLvlDesc){
        Timber.d(myItem);
        if (PickBinFlag.equals("Y")) {
            location_Type = "P";
            mILM=ItemLevelsModel.getInstance();
            mylevels = DatabaseMgr.GetItemLevels(myItem);
            whichQTY="Max";
            Integer cnt = mylevels.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < mylevels.size(); i++) {
                String lLvl = mylevels.get(i).getitemLevel().toString();
                String lLvlD = mylevels.get(i).getItemLvlDesc().toString();

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ReturnAreaActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_location);
                dialog.setTitle("Pick Levels");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                TextView message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.theText);
                message.setText("Will " + lLvl + " " + lLvlD + " \nbe Picked from this location?");
                Button buttonYes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
                Button buttonNo = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);
                buttonYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PickBinFlag = "Y";
                        myField = "QTY";
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(ReturnAreaActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_minmax);
                        TextView message = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.minMax);
                        TextView theText = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.theText);
                        if (whichQTY.equals("Max")) {
                            dialog1.setTitle("Enter Max QTY");
                            message.setText("MAX");
                            theText.setText("Enter Max QTY for this location");
                        } else {
                            dialog1.setTitle("Enter Min QTY");
                            message.setText("MAX");
                            theText.setText("Enter Min QTY for this location");
                        }


                        final TextView maxQTY = (TextView) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.editAmt);
                        Button button1 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
                        Button button2 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
                        Button button3 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
                        Button button4 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
                        Button button5 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
                        Button button6 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
                        Button button7 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn7);
                        Button button8 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn8);
                        Button button9 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn9);
                        Button button0 = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btn0);
                        Button buttonEnter = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
                        Button buttonClear = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
                        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "1";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "2";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "3";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "4";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "5";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "6";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "7";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "8";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "9";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });

                        button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = mPin + "0";
                                maxQTY.setText(mPin);
                            }
                        });


                        buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mMax = Integer.parseInt(mPin);
                                if (whichQTY.equals("Max")) {
                                    mMax = Integer.parseInt(mPin);
                                    whichQTY = "Min";
                                } else {
                                    mMin = Integer.parseInt(mPin);
                                    whichQTY = "Max";
                                }
                                mPin = "";

                                dialog1.dismiss();
                                return;
                            }

                        });

                        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mPin = "";
                                maxQTY.setText("");
                            }
                        });

                        dialog1.setCancelable(false);
                        dialog1.show();

                    }

                });

                buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PickBinFlag = "N";
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        myField = "QTY";


                    }

                });

                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();

            }

        }
```

I guess my question is how to best approach this.

Comment: You can set a listener on the dialog for the button OK, also you can make setCancelable(false). And you forgot to call dialog.show()

Comment: I edited code. I didn't copy it all into original post

Comment: Whats happening and what you expecting to happen?

Comment: I hoped that dialog would appear and wait for user input. But it is skipping over about asking      message.setText("Will " + lLvl + " " + lLvlD + " \nbe Picked from this location. and going straight to enter Min

Comment: HMMM.... well, there's a solution here that you can start the next dialog only when the user press the button on the current one. About waiting the Dialog is really a design issue (non blocking the thread) and I didnt think of a solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all you put too much unnecessary and unreadable code, so it's hard to give you exact solution.

But, in Android programming you usually use callbacks to capture the result of the `Dialog`. If you use only the `Dialog` (which I'm afraid it's not recommended solution, the `DialogFragment` should be used) you should call your methods inside button click listener. But if you use `DialogFragment` you should create your own listener. Here is an example from Android [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs):

```
public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public interface NoticeDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }

    NoticeDialogListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you have to implement listener callback inside your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
                          implements NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener{
    ...

    public void showNoticeDialog() {
        DialogFragment dialog = new NoticeDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's positive button
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's negative button
        ...
    }
}
```

Now showing dialogs in a loop is a horrible idea, because you have to wait for the result. As you may now, the loop can be replaced by [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). So the solution would be to create a method that shows the dialog. Then in your callback methods implemented in your activity, you can use that method to show new dialog, after old was closed.